# What size wire should I use to feed a subpanel in my garage?

Tags: electrical, garage, subpanel

My main panel has been upgraded to 100 amps.  I would like to add a subpanel in the garage which would supply:

- 20 amp Mig welder running on 120 volts, but later upgrade to a larger Mig welder as i am experienced at welding.
- Large jointer
- Medium sized table saw, which is 120 volts and 12 amps
- 4.5 hp portable shop vac
- A sander
- Branch circuits for good lighting, and 5 receptacles.

The main run from the 100 amp panel is 37 feet exactly, so what would be the ideal gauge and type of wire to use for feeding the sub-panel?

Is it a good idea to run the wire in metal conduit the whole span, since the feed goes though the basement ceiling and though a concrete wall in the most direct straight-line to the garage?.

I would like to do the job myself as I have seen the sloppy job the so called electrician did with the main panel, which passed hydro's inspection! I have taken and passed an electrical college course at my local college, I have an eye for detail and am a perfectionist.

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/16936/33) might be useful. [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/29077/33) might also help, and [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/13080/33) too.

Comment: If you've just upgraded from 60 to 100; and you still have the old panel, you can likely modify the old panel to work as a subpanel.

Answer (score 13):

My answer is almost always the same when talking about garage subpanels.

- 60 ampere double pole breaker in the main panel.
- 6 AWG copper wire (x4) for a run less than 75ft., 4 AWG copper wire (x4) for runs less than 150ft.
- 60 ampere panel with 60 ampere main breaker.

Unless you're running a whole bunch of stuff at once, a 60 amp panel should serve you well.

If you're running individual conductors, you'll definitely want to run it through conduit.  If you're using a cable assembly, you'll probably only use conduit if you have to. For example, if you have to protect the cable from physical damage, or it will be underground.

Comment: @SteveK, L1 & L2 hot, neutral, and ground

Comment: Solid or Stranded?

Comment: @JJS makes no difference.