# need help size of wire

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm wanting to run wire from power main box to another box to power my garage and then put lights plugs to run power tools what size wire should I use from main box to garage box it will be about 75' to 100'

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/32819/33) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**** Howdy partner, normally for something like this you should install a sub-panel, which is a mini-breaker box. Since you have both lights and tools, I would consider a sub panel pretty much mandatory. In the subpanel you may, for example, have one 15-amp circuit for the lights and 2 20-amp circuits for the tools, for a total of 55 amps. You could use a 60 amp sub panel or a 100 amp subpanel (which would leave room for expansion). If your "tools" are big machine tools like lathes, milling machines, large table saws, etc, I would recommend going with the 100-amp subpanel.

Because this is a long run you should use 1 size larger than normal for the wire. For example, for a 60-amp sub panel, the standard wire size is 6 gauge, but you should use 4 gauge for a long run. Likewise, for a 100-amp panel standard is 2 gauge, and 1/0 gauge for a long run.

Comment: I live in Tx. does that change you answer ?

Comment: @harrykopoulos Yes, I added a greeting.