# Adding work shop to garage

Tags: wiring

I am planning on building a wood workshop attached to my garage.  I have a 220 line already on the outside wall of my garage with two 20 amp breakers.  Can I install a 60amp sub box in place of the 220 line (which services my hot tub) and run 110 curcuits off that box and still have my hot tub?  If not, what guage/breakers do I need to run from my current service box to the new sub box?

Comment: [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/32819/33), and [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/29077/33) might be helpful. Have you tried searching the site, we have loads of similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

- 60 ampere double pole breaker in the main panel.
- 6 AWG copper wire (x4) for a run less than 75ft., 4 AWG copper wire (x4) for runs less than 150ft.
- 60 ampere panel with 60 ampere main breaker.