# Feeder type and size for 60 amp. subpanel

Tags: basement, subpanel

Is it possible/recommended to use E18679 (UL) ROMEX SIMPull AWG 6 CU 3 with AWG 10 ground Type NM-B 600 volts as feeder from a 60 amp breaker to install a subpanel? Subpanel will be located in basement next to main breakers panel -3' away-. 30 Amp subpanel will actually be enough for the intended purpose but i would like to have it ready in case of future expansions. I read about code requirements and ampicity table but i am not sure how to categorize this specific type of wire.

Comment: Possible duplicates [one](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/32817/33), [two](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/62795/33)