# sub panel in garage?

Tags: electrical

I have 200 amp service. I want a subpanel to handle my garage outlets hot tub and a small welder. besides normal power tools such as a miter saw table saw and ets. I have 3/4 inch pipe ran to my garage already. What are your recmondations. is 60amp #6 wire enough. Can I bulk up the wire such as a #4 run 3 runs in 3/4inch pipe even though its over kill?

Comment: Distance from main panel to garage?

Comment: 45 ft is the length

Comment: I belive nec code is 2 runs of 4g in a 3/4 inch pipe. But I am also only running 60amp breaker.

Comment: I do have a nubie electrican doing my work. I want to make sure he does not mess this up.

Comment: @Tester101s stock answer http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32817/what-size-wire-should-i-use-to-feed-a-subpanel-in-my-garage/32819#32819

Comment: What's the nameplate on the hot tub and welder say? What's the square footage of the garage?

Answer (score 1):

You need 4 wires for a subpanel (neutral and ground separated) - as such, 6AWG is all that fits - 4 AWG would require 1" conduit at a minimum (even for 3 wires.)

I don't keep this in my head - I use this, or one like it:

http://www.electrician2.com/calculators/rf_calculator.html

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. damn do you think 6g is more then enough. I really don't want to run new pipe.

Comment: I ment 6g should handle the load I want to run.I know it will not all run at once. Will the hot tub be a huge sucker for electricty causing issues with 6g?

Comment: Most hot tubs (check yours to see what it actually is) are 30A disconnect, IIRC. Depending on the welder, might want to turn the tub off when welding - not activities that are likely to overlap. Likely plenty unless you have employees (There are limits to what one guy in a garage is going to use for electricity at one time...)

Comment: As long as you're not welding and hot-tubbing at the same time it should be fine.

Comment: @friedo I hate when people say that. Load calculations are not based on what you *might* do at the same time (other than HVAC), they're based on what equipment is installed. My wife loves to relax in the hot tub, while I weld.  Not to mention, hot tubs may heat and circulate water, even when they're not actively being used.