# What size wire for 100 amp sub-panel from a 200amp main panel?

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I want to add a 100 amp sub-panel from a 200 amp main in an attached garage. It will be about 100 feet from sub to main. What gauge wire should I use? The sub panel is to hook up a 7.5 horse air compressor and a welder.

Answer (score 0):

The NEC provides wire sizing based on the type to be used and the application.

[image: NEC wire size table]
<sub>(source: [diychatroom.com](http://www.diychatroom.com/attachments/f18/80150d1390137097-100-amp-new-barn-nec.jpg))</sub>

But here is a useful question that's already got all the answers I believe you'll need:

[What size wire should I use to feed a subpanel in my garage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32817/what-size-wire-should-i-use-to-feed-a-subpanel-in-my-garage&ved=0ahUKEwi-4LXAhaDKAhVDPT4KHf3_AwUQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNHMtDOkvOg2Rlh2qC6oQOGccTusXg)